# Typescript static readonly

Tags: angular, typescript, find

I am trying to use static readonly, in my code, but i have never make something like this. I know i can have this:

```
export class Names {
    static readonly michael = { firstName: 'michael', secondName: 'jackson'};
    static readonly john = { firstName: 'John', secondName: 'Doo'};
    static readonly donald = { firstName: 'Donald', secondName: 'Trump'};
}
```

And i have

```
name = 'michael';
```

What i need is to search inside Names and find person that is michale and return his first and last name, something like this

```
found = { firstName: 'michael', secondName: 'jackson'};
```

Don't worry about names, because i just simplified the question that somebody can help me, there is no names, all static readonly value is unique. I know i can search inside array, and find, but how to search inside class?

Comment: why not using a single static read-only variable of type array which holds all the objects. Basically an array of objects?

Comment: Can you please write and answer, and we shall see. maybe that is good approach

Comment: If the question is how to convert this to the array - you can go with just `Object.values(Names)`

Comment: this is not question convert to array, i need function that will search inside names, if you know the answer, please provide, thanks

Comment: `Object.values(Names).find(p => p.name === 'michael')`

Comment: Nice, can you write and full answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all values stored in the `Names` you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). Then you can [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) required one:

```
Object.values(Names).find(p => p.name === 'michael')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Names } from './models/Names';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'angular-material';
  name = 'michael';
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (Names[this.name]) {
      console.log(Names[this.name]);
    } else {
      console.log('Not found');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case of wanting to access the value by its label you don't have to convert to an array of objects and perform a linear search (like the currently accepted answer does) - you can just do

```
export class Names {
    static readonly michael = { firstName: 'michael', secondName: 'jackson'};
    static readonly john = { firstName: 'John', secondName: 'Doo'};
    static readonly donald = { firstName: 'Donald', secondName: 'Trump'};
}

let name = 'michael';
let found = Names[name];
console.log(found);
```

This will work, but Typescript will complain about indexing by string being inappropriate for the Names type. Which it is (some minifying compilers will break this behavior).

The right answer is probably to ask a different question, as using static readonly variables' names as an index is not using the language the way it's intended, and the only way that will reliable work to search them when represented this way is the costly linear search.

A better representation of the same data would be simply

```
const names = {
  'michael': { firstName: 'michael', secondName: 'jackson' },
  'john': { firstName: 'John', secondName: 'Doo' },
  'donald': { firstName: 'Donald', secondName: 'Trump' },
};
```

Which you can then clearly and correctly access by index as `names[firstName]`. Better still would be a strictly-typed Map, and representing your data-blobs with an actual class that prevents accidental modification (i.e. with either of these structures one can do `names['donald'].secondName = 'duck'`)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a single static read-only variable of type array which holds all the objects. Basically an array of objects: In angular, this is how you'd do it.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Names } from './models/Names';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class Names implements OnInit {

  static readonly arrayOfObjects = [
  { firstName: 'michael', secondName: 'jackson'},
  { firstName: 'John', secondName: 'Doo'},
  { firstName: 'Donald', secondName: 'Trump'}
];
  constructor() {
  const filter = Names.arrayOfObjects.filter(object => object.firstName === 'michael')

   console.log(filter)
 }

}
```

Comment: Ok, and how to access john, like this arrayOfObjects[1].firstName

Comment: You mean you want to find john? @MiomirDancevic

Comment: Yes, but direct access not to find

Comment: Can you explain, what do you mean by direct access?